# Looking for a passage in the Old Testament

Tags: old-testament, angels, reference-request, killing

There's this person who prays and begs God to kill him but instead an angel comes and gives him water or something like that. I think it's in one of the first readings from April to July 2015, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a verse search question.

Comment: @curiousdannii Requests for a specific verse have generally been considered on-topic.  It is when someone asks to search for a topic ("verse**s** that say X") that it is closed.  IMO, I think that is a worthwhile distinction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably thinking of Elijah, as recounted in [1 Kings 19](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Kings%2019&version=NIV). It occurs right after Elijah's 'competition' with the prophets of Baal, and also includes the "still small voice" of God.

The Catholic Church prescribes this passage, 1 Kings 19:4–8, as the first reading for the [19th Sunday in Ordinary Time, Cycle B](http://usccb.org/bible/readings/080915.cfm), which in 2015 fell on August 9th—you were nearly, but not quite, correct in identifying the date.